# PostgresSql throws syntax error on execution

Tags: postgresql

I want to update one table by merging three other table based on some condition. losid is  common in all the three tables. My query is as follows:

```
UPDATE "rpChange"."rpChanget" AS a 
 SET "hold" = CASE  
WHEN status"."losid" IS NULL  and mUpdate."losid" IS NULL and dealer."losid" IS NULL
 THEN 'N' 
WHEN (status."losid" IS NOT NULL and COALESCE(age(NOW(), status."updateDt"),age(NOW(), status."createDt")) < '30 minutes'  and status."publishedYN"='Y') or 
(mUpdate."losid" IS NOT NULL and COALESCE(age(NOW(), mUpdate."updateDt"),age(NOW(), mUpdate."createDt")) < '30 minutes'  and mUpdate."publishedYN"='Y') or 
(dealer."losid" IS NOT NULL and COALESCE(age(NOW(), dealer."updateDt"),age(NOW(), dealer."createDt")) < '30 minutes'  and dealer."publishedYN"='Y')
 THEN 'Y' 
  END 
 ,"holdR" = CASE  
  WHEN status."losid" IS NULL  and mUpdate."losid" IS NULL and dealer."losid" IS NULL
 THEN NULL 
WHEN (status."losid" IS NOT NULL and COALESCE(age(NOW(), status."updateDt"),age(NOW(), status."createDt")) < '30 minutes'  and status."publishedYN"='Y') or 
(mUpdate."losid" IS NOT NULL and COALESCE(age(NOW(), mUpdate."updateDt"),age(NOW(), mUpdate."createDt")) < '30 minutes'  and mUpdate."publishedYN"='Y') or 
(dealer."losid" IS NOT NULL and COALESCE(age(NOW(), dealer."updateDt"),age(NOW(), dealer."createDt")) < '30 minutes'  and dealer."publishedYN"='Y')
 THEN 'SCHEDULED FOR LATER'
  END 
 FROM "statuss"."statusSt" AS status 
 ,"mUpdates"."mUpdateSt" AS mUpdate
 , "dealers"."dealerSt" AS dealer
 WHERE status."losid" = a."losid" 
 AND mUpdate."losid" = a."losid"
 AND dealer."losid" = a."losid";
```

The above query works before adding COALESCE() ,but after adding  it is throwing syntax error. Can anyone please help me , what am doing wrong here.

Comment: First try the SQL in a database tool. My uninformed guess here is that COALESCE has problems with date time types, either as parameter or comparing the result with another date time value.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes I tried in database tool , got same error. I am using COALESCE to  check createDt only when the updateDt is null. Is there anyother option to do that.

Comment: Show the exact error you're getting.

Comment: I mean just posting it in SO shows via syntax highlighting that your quotes are screwed right from the start: `WHEN status"`

Comment: @404 Thanks you are right . Sorry I missed some Quotes that causes problem.